# Why request to api work in browser but not in my python request?

Tags: python, http, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'am newbi in scrappring and I try to learn how it works! I'am trying to access to an api but it does not work in my python request. howerver, it works in my browser.

the url = https://www.leboncoin.fr/_next/data/9RwG8_w8p1ZNfDRzX-lzV/ClassifiedAd.json?cat=ventes_immobilieres&id=2338252753

```
import requests
params = {
  'cat':'ventes_immobilieres',
  'id': '2338252753'
}

url = "https://www.leboncoin.fr/_next/data/9RwG8_w8p1ZNfDRzX-lzV/ClassifiedAd.json"
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

I get 403 Error if I do  `r.status` and `r.text` tells me that I have to go on the website if I want to see this ad. Howerver, in my browser it works and I get all the JSON DATA. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the url has added a captcha control to the address you sent the request to prevent automatic requests.

When you make a request from the browser, browser skips the captcha step and see the data because the browser keeps the required value to pass the captcha in local storage or cache. Or server saves your client as human. There is diffent ways to do it.

To avoid this prob, you can use python libraries for captcha solving. For instance; ( PS: I am not owner of the repo and i don't know status of this repo. Just for giving the idea. )

- https://github.com/ptigas/simple-captcha-solver